# Why do derivatives of functions exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

Consider following function:

$f(x)=x^2  \sin{\frac{1}{x} }$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Why does the derivative of $f(x)$ exist? Find the deriviative and determine whether or not it is continous.

Now it is easy to find the derivative:

$f'(x)=2x \sin{\frac{1}{x}}-\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$. $(*)$

One can further find that the derivative exists at $x=0$ but is not continous at that point.

All that is clear to me but the explenation given for its existance is the chain rule [1](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch4.pdf).
I was taught the rule as a means for computing derivatives of computing dervivatives of products. How does the chain rule convey existance of a derivative?

Edit: Typo: Changed $\cos{x}$ in $(*)$ to $\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$

[www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch4.pdf](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch4.pdf)

Comment: if you have two functions that are differentiable on some open region $D$, the chain rule tells you that their product $f\cdot g$ is differentiable on that region AND how to explicitly calculate the derivative of $f\cdot g$ assuming you know the derivatives of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

Comment: I have looked at your class notes, theorem 4.20 (Chain Rule).  It says "If
$f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $g$ is differentiable at $f(c)$, then $g◦f: A→\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c$."  Thus, as set forth in your school notes, the chain rule conveys the existence of a derivative.

Comment: And it's *not* about derivatives of products but about derivatives of composites. Those derivatives (of composites) happen to *be* products.

Comment: and $f'(x) = 2 x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)$

Comment: @Justpassingby I admit I got a bit confused: I know that the chain rule and product rule are two different things

Comment: @user1952009 Yes thats a typo...

Comment: @ForgotALot Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @user159517 Thx

Comment: and you should re-prove the derivative formulas $(fg)' , (f \circ g)' , (e^g)' , (f^n)'$

Comment: @ShadowLights Once you move to multivariable calculus, you’ll find that the product rule is a special case of the chain rule.

Comment: It's a good question.  To say "the derivative is ..." implies "the derivative exists" but we sometimes forget it, especially when we say "the derivative is ... " and we give a formula that isn't defined everywhere.  But the chain rule (and product rule) states two things.   If the derivative of the components exist then the derivative of the chain exists, and secondly what the derivative is.  We tend to forget the first.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see how a general differentiation rule can justify the existence of $f'(0)$. Instead, you have to resort to the definition:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}h\sin(1/h)=0,$$
where the last equality may be justified by noting that $-h\le h\sin(1/h)\le h$ and applying the squeeze law.

Comment: – or did I misread the quesetion? It looked to me that you were asking about justification for the existence of $f'(0)$. If that is not what you meant, perhaps you could clarify the question.